# Disable GRUB 2 and Plymouth

Tags: grub2, plymouth

I have a dual-boot system with Linux 12.04 and Windows 7.
I use Windows Boot Manager, which I configured with EasyBCD through Windows.

Now, when I start up Ubuntu, GRUB appears, making me choose Ubuntu again.
How can I disable GRUB?

I would like to disable Plymouth as well, because my resolution (1366x768) is not supported at all, and I already gave up trying to fix it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Get [grub customizer](http://www.unixmen.com/grub-customizer-2-5-5-is-available-customize-grubburg-from-a-gui-interface/), go to Preferences, disable show menu, and click save.

You can't remove plymouth, but you can disable the splash. Remove the package "plymouth-label".

Comment: Can I unistall grub customizer after that?

Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, you can remove grub customizer after that. The other way is to manually edit /etc/grub/default, change GRUB_TIMEOUT to 0, and sudo update-grub. I usually recommend grub customizer bceause it is generally handy :)