# Uninstall GRUB and Plymouth

Tags: grub2, uninstall, plymouth

I have questions about Plymouth and GRUB.

My problem with Plymouth is that it is ugly and slow. Which, as far has I know, is the opposite of what it should be.

*Is there any way to REMOVE (not disable, I tried and it didn't work) Plymouth*?
*OR if I can't, is there any Linux distro without Plymouth, which is easy to use*?

I thought about Debian, but it probably is for more experienced users than me.

My problem with GRUB is that I don't need it. Oh, and it is also ugly. But that is not the prime point. I want to use the Windows Boot Manager as my boot manager to manage my Windows 7-Linux dual-boot.

When I installed 12.04, creating a /boot partition, when I selected Ubuntu in Windows Boot Manager, it didn't booted directly to Ubuntu, but GRUB appeared first.

If anybody wants to see which tutorial I consulted, here is the [link](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/).

What I want is that, if I select Ubuntu, I want it to boot quickly and without GRUB (or I wouldn't spend my time finding a way to use Windows Boot Manager instead of GRUB), just like Windows.

If there's no solution, can anybody tell me about some distro without GRUB and Plymouth? Or at least that I can install without GRUB?

Comment: Yes you need it, ok not GRUB but you need a Bootloader, there's BURG for one, there's also LiLo and a lot more see [Wikipedia:Free boot loaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_boot_loaders), [and you can disable Plymouth](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180077/disable-grub-2-and-plymouth).

Comment: Ok, I might stand GRUB, but I hate and i WON'T use Plymouth. Any distro without that ****?

Comment: You can find the list of Plymouth enabled distro's [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/Distributions) and then you can rule out the ones that don't use it.

Comment: Linux Mint does not use Plymouth?

Comment: It does, but it's only a black screen.